# Elements in a local ring written as a sum.

Tags: polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

Set $A$ as a commutative noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ generated by $m_1,\ldots,m_n$.

I believe, every element $a \in A$ can be written as a finite sum:
\begin{align*}
a= \sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_n \geq 0} a_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}m_1^{k_1}\ldots m_n^{k_n}
\end{align*}
with $a_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}\in A \setminus \mathfrak{m}$.

Am I wrong?

EDIT:

and there fore every element $\alpha \in A[[X]]$
can be written as (perhaps not infinite sum):
\begin{align*}
\alpha= \sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_n,k_{n+1} \geq 0} a_{k_1,\ldots,k_n,k_{n+1}}m_1^{k_1}\ldots m_n^{k_n}X^{k_{n+1}}
\end{align*}
with $a_{k_1,\ldots,k_n,k_{n+1}} \in A\setminus \mathfrak{m}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $a\in \frak{m}$, it is trivial. And when $a\notin \frak{m}$, we define $a_{0,\dots,0}:=a$ and otherwise $a_{k_1\dots k_n}=0$, then $a=a_{0,\dots,0}m_1^{0}\cdots m_n^{0}$.

EDIT:

That is also true.
First we write $\alpha=\sum_{k_{n+1}\ge 0}\alpha_{k_{n+1}}X^{k_{n+1}}$, and we apply the above fact for each $\alpha_{k_{n+1}}\in A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is my edit correct aswell?

Comment: Yes. I added my post.

Comment: Generally speaking: are the $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ algebraically independent? Because then $A[X] \cong A^{\times}[m_1,\ldots,m_n,X]A \cong A[m_1,\ldots,m_n,X]$. I guess so, because I have written, that every regular sequence is algebraically Independent, as is $m_1,\ldots,m_n$.

Comment: The answer is no: $A^{\times}$ is not even a ring :D